# Preencher lista a partir de uma input

Tags: javascript, html, input

Tenho uma `input` que após ser preenchida e apertamos <kbd>Enter</kbd>, ela cria uma lista com `checkbox`'s. O problema é que ela ao ser preenchida novamente, ela edita o item da lista já criado e eu quero criar um novo item, não editar o anterior.

Eu quero fazer com que a lista ao ser preenchida com o `input`, crie várias `li`'s e não apenas uma e fique editando/sobrescrevendo a mesma. Como posso fazer isso?

```
// verifica se a tecla apertada é o enter

function OnEnter(evt) {
    var key_code = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode :
    evt.charCode ? evt.charCode :
    evt.which ? evt.which : void 0;

    if (key_code == 13) {
        return true;
    }
}
var j = 1;

function recarrega(e) {
    if(OnEnter(e))
    {
        var p = document.getElementById('Foo');
        var filhos = p.childNodes;
        for (i = filhos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (filhos[i].tagName == 'LI') {
                p.removeChild(filhos[i]);
            }
        }

        var tarefa = document.getElementById("my_span").value;

        document.getElementById("my_span").value = "";

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        p.appendChild(li);
        li.id = 'my_span'+ j;
        li.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='ckb" + j + "' value='" + j + "' onclick='my_fun(" + j + ");'>" + tarefa;

        j++;

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// quando marco o checkbox ele risca a string da li

function my_fun(j) {
    var chkbox = "ckb" + j;
    var my_span = "my_span" + j;
    var msg = chkbox + " " + my_span;
    if ($("#ckb"+ j).is(':checked')) {
        document.getElementById(my_span).style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(my_span).style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
}
```

```
<form>
    <label for="ctarefa">Tarefas:</label>
    <input onkeypress="return recarrega(event);" type="text" id='my_span'/><br />
    <div class="boxLista">
        <ul id="Foo">

        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português! Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta está muito ampla, o padrão da comunidade são perguntas objetivas e que possuam ao menos uma resposta correta, como pode ser visto na [help] no link [ask]. Esta sua pergunta, além de muito ampla pode dar margem a opniões. Faça um passeio pelo [tour] e depois você pode [edit] sua pergunta para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Vamos lá. Antes de tentar entender teu problema vou te dar umas dicas: 1. Quase todo o conteúdo do site é alguém que precisa de **ajuda**, logo colocar **ajuda/help/socorro** e afins no título é algo extremamente redundante. 2. Nós sabemos pelas tags qual a linguagem ou tecnologia que você precisa de ajuda, então também é redundante colocar isso no título da pergunta (salvo raras exceções). 3. O título deve ser uma descrição (muito) breve do seu problema, algo que dê uma "ideia" do que você precisa. 4. Dedique um tempo para escrever sua pergunta, explique seu problema de uma forma que [+]

Comment: [+] alguém que não conheça nada do seu projeto possa te ajudar. Veja [ask], [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](/help/mcve) e visite o [tour], isso vai te ajudar (e muito). Você pode editar sua pergunta a qualquer momento, clicando em [edit]. Aliás, bem vindo ao [pt.so].

Comment: O que queres dizer com "e fique editando a mesma"? O que está a falhar no código que tens? podes descrever melhor o que não consegues pôr a funcionar?

Comment: sempre que preenche a input e dou enter cria uma <li> com o valor preenchido e limpa o input, quando preencho de novo gostaria que cria-se outra <li> com a nova entrada mas meu codigo edita a <li> anterior

Comment: Marcio, você precisa **[edit]** sua pergunta para que ela seja votada para reabertura. Por favor, confira as dicas do jbueno, são importantes.

Comment: dei uma melhorada na explicação acredito que ja da para entender a parte onde estou com dificuldade

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi os problemas e dei uma melhorada no código

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
function OnEnter(evt) {

    var key_code = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode :

    evt.charCode ? evt.charCode :

    evt.which ? evt.which : void 0;

    if (key_code == 13) {
        return true;
    }
}

var j = 1;

function recarrega(e) {

    if(OnEnter(e))
    {

        var p = document.getElementById('Foo');

        var filhos = p.childNodes;

        for (i = filhos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            if (filhos[i].tagName == 'LI') {
                p.appendChild(filhos[i]);
            }
        }

        var tarefa = document.getElementById("my_span").value;

        document.getElementById("my_span").value = "";

        var li = document.createElement('li');

        var label = " <label for='ckb" + j + "' id='lbl"+j+"'>"+tarefa+"</label>"
        p.appendChild(li);
        li.setAttribute("ondblclick","HabilitaInput("+j+")")
        li.id = 'my_span'+ j;
        li.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' id='ckb" + j + "' value='" + j + "' onclick='my_fun(" + j + ");'>"+"<input type='text' id='input" + j + "' value='" + tarefa + "' style='display: none' onkeypress='return atualizaTarefa(this,"+j+",event);'>"  + label;


        j++;

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// quando marco o checkbox ele risca a string da li

function my_fun(j) {

    var chkbox = "ckb" + j;

    var my_span = "my_span" + j;

    var msg = chkbox + " " + my_span;

    if ($("#ckb"+ j).is(':checked')) {
        document.getElementById(my_span).style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    } 

else {
        document.getElementById(my_span).style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
}
function HabilitaInput(index){

    var idInput = "input"+index;
    document.getElementById(idInput).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(idInput).focus();
}
function atualizaTarefa(element,index,e){
    if(OnEnter(e)){
        var newtarefa = element.value;
        var idInput = "input"+index;
        var idLbl = "lbl"+index;
        document.getElementById(idLbl).innerHTML =newtarefa; 
        document.getElementById(idInput).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>

            <label for="ctarefa">Tarefas:</label>

            <input onkeypress="return recarrega(event);" type="text" id='my_span'/><br />

            <div class="boxLista">

                <ul id="Foo">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se pudesse dizer que problemas resolveu, a resposta ganharia muito